# How to use chessboard?

Tags: chessboard

I try to use chessboard package but cannot obtain anything:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}                % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
\geometry{letterpaper}                   % ... or a4paper or a5paper or ... 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[french]{varioref}
\usepackage{pgfcore}
\usepackage{pgfbaseshapes}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{chessfss}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{skak}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode,polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text]{Gill Sans}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Andale Mono}

\setchessboard{ 
    smallboard,
    showmover=false}
\newchessgame
\chessboard 

\end{document}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

- Add `\begin{document}` before `\chessboard`.
- Load the package `xskak` instead of `skak`. If you want to use `skak`, use `\newgame` instead of `\newchessgame`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chessboard,xskak}
\setchessboard{ 
    smallboard,
    showmover=false}
\begin{document}
\newchessgame
\chessboard 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: These things describe the wonderfulness of Latex...

Comment: Thanks a lot. I begin to understand how chessboard works.